# I want ggplotly tooltip to only show the number on hover

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the following graph:

```
g <- ggplot(data1) +
        theme_bw()+
        theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
         #axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5),
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
         axis.line.x = element_line(),
         axis.title.x =       element_blank(),
         axis.title.y =       element_blank(),
         panel.border =element_blank(),
         legend.position = "none") +

                geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.integer(Category) - w/2,xmax = as.integer(Category) + w/2, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax,fill = Impact, Revnue = valuelabel),    
                    colour = "black") +
                    scale_x_discrete(limits = levels) +
                    scale_fill_manual(values = (c("Decrease" = "red", "Increase" = "green", "Total" = "black")))

g <- g +
    geom_segment(data = data1[1:(nrow(data1) -1),],aes(x = xmin,
                                                       xend = xmax,
                                                       y = ymin,
                                                       yend = ymin)) +
         coord_cartesian(xlim= c(min(as.integer(data1$Category)), max(as.integer(data1$Category))),ylim=c(max(data1$ymin)*0.9, max(c(data1$ymin*1.03,data1$ymax*1.03))))


yrevenuecords <- if (data1$Impact == "Decrease"){min(data1$ymin,data1$ymax)} else {max(data1$ymin,data1$ymax)}

    g <- g + geom_text(aes(x = as.integer(Category),
                           y = ifelse(Impact=="Decrease",ymin*0.99,ymin*1.01), label = css(valuelabel), PriorMonth = revpriormonth), colour = "black")
    
    g <- g + geom_text(aes(x = as.integer(Category),
                           y = max(c(ymin*1.02,ymax*1.02)), label = css(arpu)), colour = "black")
                           
    g <- g + geom_text(aes(x = as.integer(Category),
                           y = max(c(ymin*1.03,ymax*1.03)), label = css(lines)), colour = "black")                     
    
    g <- ggplotly(g, tooltip = c("PriorMonth") )
```

The resulting tooltip looks like this:

```
revpriormonth: 5
```

Is there a way to only extract the number without the text? I would like my tooltip to only show `5` without the `revpriormonth` before.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Can you share how `g` is defined? i.e. `g <- ggplot(...)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to be using is `text` as the aesthetic in `geom_text`.

So try adding `text = revpriormonth` inside `geom_text(aes())`, and then change `tooltip` to `tooltip = c("text")`.